# Extract and List Matching Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to compare two columns (A and B) containing company names, find any names that are an exact match, and list them in column C. With the code below I don't get an error but nothing happens. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

```
Sub match()
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To LastRow

Set Row2Name = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2)
Set Row1Name = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
Set MatchName = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)

If Cells(i, 2) = Row1Name Then
Row2Name.Copy
MatchName.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: For starters this should be Set MatchName = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3) if column C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to process in memory with arrays and avoid loops when faster 'prove existence' methods are available..

```
Sub matchComps()
    Dim i As long, j As long, arrA as variant, arrB as variant, arrC as variant

    with workSheets("Sheet1")
        arrA = .range(.cells(3, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup)).value2
        arrb = .range(.cells(3, "B"), .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup)).value2
        redim arrc(1 to application.min(ubound(arra, 1) ,ubound(arrb, 1)), 1 to 1)

        for i= lbound(arra, 1) to ubound(arra, 1) 
            if not iserror(application.match(arra(i, 1), arrb, 0)) then
                j=j+1
                arrc(j,1) = arra(i, 1)
            end if
        next i

        .cells(3, "C").resize(ubound(arrc, 1), ubound(arrc, 2)) = arrc
    end with

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the appropriate way to ask a follow up question? I intended to use a method similar to my original code and modify it to do something more complex. I am not familiar with arrays so modifying the code is a bit daunting

Comment: Just ask your new question with updated code and/or sample data. If you feel it would help, link back to this question with a note that says 'follow up to this'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085540/filter-and-modify-database-with-array - thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Here is a tidied version with correctly using column C i.e.

`Set MatchName = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3) if column C`.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub matching()
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, Row2Name As Range, Row1Name  As Range, MatchName As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 3 To LastRow

            Set Row2Name = .Cells(i, 2)
            Set Row1Name = .Cells(i, 1)
            Set MatchName = .Cells(i, 3)

            If .Cells(i, 2) = Row1Name Then
                Row2Name.Copy
                MatchName.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Which is essentially this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub matching()
    Dim i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 3 To .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(i, 1) = .Cells(i, 2) Then .Cells(i, 3) = .Cells(i, 2)
        Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

For large numbers of rows you could do this all in memory using an array.

```
Public Sub matching()
    Dim arr(), i As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns(3).ClearContents
        arr = .Range("A3:C" & .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            If arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 2) Then arr(i, 3) = arr(i, 2)
        Next i
        .Cells(3, 1).Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, however I'm getting the same result even after making these changes. Nothing happens..

Comment: It definitely does if column A = B for a row greater than  2 then column C gets column B 's value.

Comment: Can you show some data otherwise? Try the bottom version aswell which is a reduced version.

Comment: Have you got screenupdating turned off or something?

Comment: And step through the code with F8 and verify loop is entered and value of .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: screenupdating is on.. would a massive amount of rows affect the macro? All data is text and the way you describe the function in your first comment is how it should be.

Comment: could it be an issue with macro security?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173922/discussion-between-qharr-and-carter).

Comment: thanks for your help.. for some reason none of these did anything but the answer above did..

Comment: Not sure what to say. Did you try running them again today? At least you have a solution :-)

Comment: :-( sad face then. Sorry.

Comment: don't be! I am really confused why your initial code didn't modify anything - any ideas?