# Filter and Modify Data with Array

Tags: vba, excel

This is a follow up post to [Extract and List Matching Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071131/extract-and-list-matching-cells/51072136?noredirect=1#comment89158709_51072136)

Right now the code below compares two columns in the same sheet (A and B) containing company names. It finds any names that are an exact match, and lists them in column C.

I want to modify this to use the actual data sheets from which column A and B are derived. Column A is derived from sheet 2, column AF. Column B is derived from sheet 3, column L. Data starts in cell 2.

I'd also like to modify the result:

**Currently:** if column A = B for a row greater than 2 then column C gets column B 's value

**Goal:** if Sheet2.Column AF = Sheet3.Column L for a row greater than 2 then New Sheet gets corresponding row from Sheet3

```
Sub matchComps()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, arrA As Variant, arrB As Variant, arrC As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        arrA = .Range(.Cells(3, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2
        arrB = .Range(.Cells(3, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
        ReDim arrC(1 To Application.Min(UBound(arrA, 1), UBound(arrB, 1)), 1 To 1)

        For i = LBound(arrA, 1) To UBound(arrA, 1)
            If Not IsError(Application.match(arrA(i, 1), arrB, 0)) Then
                j = j + 1
                arrC(j, 1) = arrA(i, 1)
            End If
        Next i

        .Cells(3, "C").Resize(UBound(arrC, 1), UBound(arrC, 2)) = arrC
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This will effectively create a new data sheet in sheet (4) for all companies in sheet (3) that match companies in sheet (2) using data from Sheet (3).

Comment: Using the term "database" for a sheet containing data is a bit misleading. People reading this will expect this is an Excel/Access question. Anyway, the way I read your question, the only thing that needs to be altered is .`Cells(3, "C").Resize(UBound(arrC, 1), UBound(arrC, 2)) = arrC` which should simply insert the data in a new sheet instead. This is trivially easy to do, so I need to ask if this indeed is your question?

Comment: The differences are that the references are now in separate sheets, the inserted data is on a NEW sheet, and instead of one cell i'd like the entire corresponding row from sheet 3. Hope this helps