# if and for loop contained inside while loop VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to write some code that loops throw a column of data in one column ad matches it with data in another column all in the same sheet. When the two data points are matched the corresponding data will be copied to beside the first data point. The simplest way of putting it is I have a if statement inside a for Staten inside a while loop. I believe the issue is I am either not while looping correctly or I am not assigning the data correctly, either way the script is not writing any data to the columns they or supposed to write to. Any help in getting this script working would be appreciated see code below.

```
Sub s()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim pointer As Integer

    pointer = 1

    Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(pointer, 13) <> ""

        For i = 1 To 305
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(i, 1).Value = 
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(pointer, 13).Value Then

                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(pointer, 14).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(i, 2).Value

                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(pointer, 15).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(i, 3).Value
            End If
            pointer = pointer + 1
        Next i
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You know this goes row by row matching.  So row 1 on one sheet will need to match row 1 on the second, row 2 to row 2 and so on.  It is not searching the column in full?

Comment: `If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(i, 1).Value = _` <~ line continuation is mandatory if the instruction is going to be continued on the next line

Comment: Do you have to do this with VBA? It sounds like Index/Match could do this very easily.

Comment: Why not use index/match for the output?  Looks like you're making a loop for the sake of having a loop, rather than aiding the output.

Comment: ...when i started typing, there were no comments...

Comment: @Scott Craner  Oh that is not what I was trying to do I wanted 1 row to search for a match with all rows of a column.

Comment: Then you will need 2 loops or use `Application.Match` if you are going with the loops, load everything into variant arrays and loop those instead of the ranges on the worksheet.

Comment: Actually move: `pointer = pointer + 1` outside the for loop.  But I would still recommend for speed the use of variant arrays.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071131/extract-and-list-matching-cells/51072136#51072136

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `pointer = pointer + 1` outside the For Loop

```
Sub s()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim pointer As Long

    pointer = 1
    Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(pointer, 13) <> ""
        For i = 1 To 305
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(i, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(pointer, 13).Value Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(pointer, 14).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(i, 2).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(pointer, 15).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(i, 3).Value
            End If
        Next i
        pointer = pointer + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

---

But as stated in my comments using variant arrays will be quicker:

```
Sub s()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MPACSCodesedited")
        lastrw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim outarr As Variant
        outarr = .Range(.Cells(1, 13), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).row,15)).Value

        Dim SearchArr As Variant
        SearchArr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row, 3))

        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(outarr, 1) To UBound(outarr, 1)
            Dim j As Long
            For j = LBound(SearchArr, 1) To UBound(SearchArr, 1)
                If SearchArr(j, 1) = outarr(i, 1) Then
                    outarr(i, 2) = SearchArr(j, 2)
                    outarr(i, 3) = SearchArr(j, 3)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        .Range(.Cells(1, 13), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp)).Value = outarr
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: With [87,000 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51251587/id-code-matching-script-extremely-slow), that is still a lot of looping.  For maximum speed, I'd add a row index to the 2D array (or just a separate pointer array), sort it, use a binary search instead of the double looping, re-sort it by row index when done and dump the array back.

Comment: @Scott Craner  I am trying this script however it is not looping through all the values. Do you have any suggestions.

Comment: Then one of the arrays are not grabbing everything.  I have adjusted the first, but the second array, the 305 rows was set by you.  Is that 305 a set number or is the data in columns A:C dynamic? @user9730643

Comment: @ScottCraner I hardcoded that value and now it is 891375 instead of 305

Comment: @user9730643 well, I can only go off the information in the question.  See edit.  I have made it dynamic.