# ID code matching script extremely slow

Tags: vba, excel

I have a quick script that runs through one column and finds the corresponding matching column in the other row. It then runs through takes the columns to to the right of the first matched value and writes them in the right column of the corresponding matching column. At the moment the code works however for the 87000 rows I need to search it is extremely slow. Does anyone have any suggestions on a way I could increase the speed at this script runs throw a large amount of rows and data.

```
Sub s()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim pointer As Long

    pointer = 1
    Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(pointer, 13) <> ""
        For i = 1 To 305
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(i, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(pointer, 13).Value Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(pointer, 14).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(i, 2).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(pointer, 15).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(i, 3).Value
                 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(pointer, 16).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited").Cells(i, 4).Value
            End If
        Next i
        pointer = pointer + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe don't do so many cell lookups -- move the sheet reference to a separate variable, maybe grab a reference to the row first and do column lookups instead of always looks for a specific cell. Also, what do you mean by "extremely slow"? 10 seconds? 10 minutes?

Comment: @Cory  By extremely slow I mean 24 hours

Comment: did you try my variant array version from your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089279/if-and-for-loop-contained-inside-while-loop-vba

Comment: 24 hours? That is insane. Does your worksheet have a lot of formulas? Maybe start with disabling automatic recalculation at the beginning of this code and turn it back on afterwards: `Application.Calculation = xlManual`, then run your code, then `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` afterwards.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ that's sticking one's head in the sand. Working off an in-memory 2D array would be MUCH more efficient, and wouldn't require any tweaking of global `Application` state. Scott already answered that question, OP just ignored it.

Comment: Where does the 305 come from?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPACSCodesedited")
> ```

This `Worksheet` object is dereferenced once per iteration in the `Do While` loop, then twice in the `If` condition, and if that condition evaluates to `True`, it's dereferenced 6 more times, every time.

If sheet `MPACSCodesedited` exists at compile time, select it in the *Project Explorer* (Ctrl+R), then access its properties (F4), and give it a meaningful `(Name)` property value - say, `MPACSCodesSheet`.

Congratulations, you've just eliminated the need to dereference that object even *once* - VBA takes that `(Name)` property value and creates a global/project-scope object variable that you can use anywhere to refer to that worksheet:

```
Do While MPACSCodesSheet.Cells(pointer, 13) <> ""
```

If that cell contains an error value (e.g. `#N/A`), then you have a *type mismatch* error happening right here. Before you can compare a cell value with anything, you need to make sure you've not looking at an error, using the `IsError` function.

But first things first.

First thing to address is the fact that you're accessing that worksheet cell by cell, both reading and writing: that is inherently inefficient.

You can stick your head in the sand and turn off automatic calculation and worksheet events and whatnot, but none of that would be needed if you dumped the contents into a 2D array, iterated that array, wrote to that array, and then dumped the array onto the worksheet as a single operation.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51089525/1188513) from your previous question tells you exactly what you need to do.